# Why when importing Certain libraries for a task-pane add-in does the addin work in office online but show up blank in desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-js

Within App.js as part of the taskpane addin if I have an import statement like

```
import {string} from "mathjs";
```

The addin loads and works perfectly in office online but for the desktop version shows a blank page. 
If I remove this import statement the addin works fine in the desktop version.

```
// All Work
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, ButtonType} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import Progress from './Progress';
import {Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardTitle} from "reactstrap";
import axios from "axios";
// Breaks it
import {string} from "mathjs";
```

No error messages: Still working on getting desktop debugging to work correctly in visual studio.

Comment: The browser that desktop Office uses for the task pane varies depending on your version of Office and, if you are testing on desktop Windows, your version of Windows. What are your versions? Also, what browser are you using when it works on Office Online. Does it fail if you use other browsers?

Comment: I think another important question is also whether you're using webpack or babel or whatever else to bundle your dependencies -- and also if you're including polyfills.  On most versions of Office, IE11 is used as the browser that renders the taskpane, and so it may require some polyfills for things that "just work" in Chrome / Edge / etc.

Comment: As for debugging:  you should be able to attach the JavaScript debugger using Visual Studio 2017 or F12 tools (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).  This should let you see any errors that are popping up.  (Pro tip:  if those are startup issues, try entering "window.location.reload()" into the console so that it reloads after you're already attached)